# How to save a session variable in drupal 7?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, session-variables

i would like use a variable session ($_session) but it doesn't work in Drupal 7. What are the possibilities in Drupal 7 in order to save variable session.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can try this.

```
function lists_session($key, $value = NULL) {
  static $storage;
  if ($value) {
    $storage[$key] = $value ;
    $_SESSION['lists'][$key] = $value ;   // I use 'lists' in case some other module uses 'type' in $_SESSION
  }
  else if (empty($storage[$key]) && isset($_SESSION['lists'][$key])) {
    $storage[$key] = $_SESSION['lists'][$key];
  }
  return $storage[$key];
}
```

So, to save a variable in Session:

```
lists_session("s_key", "value");
```

And to retrieve the value, just use:

```
$myVar = lists_session("s_key");
```

Comment: Do we also need a session_start or one already exists in drupal?

Comment: You can use [`drupal_session_start()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!session.inc/function/drupal_session_start/7). It will start the session if it is not already started.

Comment: You shouldn't need to call ```drupal_session_start()```. As soon as data is added to ```$_SESSION``` then Drupal will save that session at the end of the request. If you have to call ```drupal_session_start()``` directly then something is wrong.

Comment: Note ([as described on drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/node/360542#comment-1446254)), if someone else wonders: `static $storage` is used to save the data for the *current request* and `$_SESSION` is used to save the data for *future requests*.

Comment: For someone get stuck in using $_SESSION. If @MuhammadReda's answer does not help. Please check your database have user with uid=0 [link]https://www.drupal.org/node/315830 and remember Configuration > Performance > Clear Cache

Answer (score 7):

I have no problem of using the $_SESSION variable in my own module. Just keep in mind to create a unique sub key for your data.

```
$_SESSION['mydata'] = array(of your data);
```

Comment: I would like to have access to session variables in a php page. This page is available on my drupal website with the lightbox2 module. And i need to use session variables to communicate between theses pages. So, the code is : $_SESSION['background_menu'] = 'yellow';

And in my php page : echo $_SESSION['background_menu']?> I have also the session_start but it doesn't work. Help :)

Comment: The Drupal bootstrap will do the session_start. So how is your php-code run. Is it a drupal module or do you have standalone php-scripts?

Comment: $_SESSION variable works in Drupal 7. So something in your own code is not working. Have you tested you code in other enviroment?

Answer (score 1):

Remember to serialise your data such as array, obj... before save to session.
$arr = array();
$_SESSION['mysession'] = serialise($arr);